# pass arguments to `before_first_request_funcs` in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want the function I pass to `before_first_request_funcs` the ability to access `app.config` object.
Can I pass an argument to the function somehow?
Access the "current app object" (it is not really global and I can just access it, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just access the `current_app`. This is the way to do it. The `before_first_request` callback run inside the app context.